# Intersection of Compact Sets Is Not Compact

Tags: general-topology

What is an example of a topological space $X$ such that $C,K\subseteq X$; $C$ is closed; $K$ is compact; and $C\cap K$ is *not* compact?

I know that $X$ can be neither Hausdorff nor finite.

I am interested in this question because I recently read the following definition (in a Rudin book):

> If $\left(X,\tau\right)$ is a topological space and $\infty\not\in X$, then $\left(X_\infty,\tau_\infty\right)$, where $X_\infty=X\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$ and every $U\in\tau_\infty$ is such that $U\in\tau$ or $U^c\subseteq X$ is compact, is a topological space.

I believe that this definition requires that $U^c\subseteq X$ be compact *and* closed.

**Edit**: The first question was my attempt to show that if $U,V\in\tau_\infty$ are such that $U\in\tau$ and $V^c\subseteq X$ is compact, then $\left(U\cup V\right)^c=U^c\cap V^c$ is not compact. However, this holds, as the comments show. A correct counter-example would be to show that if $U,V\in\tau_\infty$ are such that $U^c,V^c\subseteq X$ are compact, then $\left(U\cup V\right)^c=U^c\cap V^c$ is not compact, as Rob Arthan shows in his answer.

Comment: $C \cap K$ is a (relatively) closed subset of $K$, hence compact.

Comment: For any open cover ${\cal U}$ of $C$, adding $K\setminus C$ to ${\cal U}$ gives an open cover of $K$. It must therefore have a finite subcover; removing $K\setminus C$ from it gives a cover of $C$.

Comment: And yes, if you take a non-closed (quasi)compact $K \subset X$, let $U = X_{\infty}\setminus K$, then $U \cap X \notin \tau_{\infty}$. Does Rudin only consider Hausdorff spaces there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the intersection of a closed set and a compact set always compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35038/is-the-intersection-of-a-closed-set-and-a-compact-set-always-compact)

Comment: @zzuussee: this is about topological spaces not metric spaces and so not a duplicate of the question you cite.

Comment: @RobArthan I was referring to the answer given in the corresponding question as well

Comment: @zzuussee: the answer doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm reading this question as asking about the OP's belief in the last sentence as well as just about the sentence with the question mark at the beginning (which has been addressed in the comments: the intersection $C \cap K$ of a closed set $C$ and a compact set $K$ is always compact).

In a space that isn't Hausdorff, compact sets aren't necessarily closed under intersections. E.g., take $(X, \tau)$ to be the [line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold): then (using a notation that I hope is obvious),  $A = [0_a, 1]$ and $B = [0_b, 1]$ are both compact but $A \cap B = (0_a, 1] = (0_b, 1]$ is not compact. So in Rudin's definition, you do indeed need to require $U^{c}$ to be compact **and closed** for the proposed set of open sets $\tau_{\infty}$ to satisfy the axioms of a topological space.

N.b., with the new MSE theme you can barely see it, but the words "line with two origins" above are a link to the Wikipedia page on that subject.

Comment: Perhaps, now that I finally did bin my answer, it's worth just saying that there is indeed no example of what OP asks for (as in the comments to their question).

Comment: @Matt: thanks for the reminder. I've edited my answer to address that.